# Окно поверх других WinApi, C#

Tags: c#, winapi

Всем привет, автоматизирую программу для клиента. Т.е. отправляю команды "Чужой" программе.
Проблема в том, что при запуске "Чужой" программы, если при этом запущен браузер или любое другое приложение, фокус на нужную программу не приходит, пока я не кликну мышкой. Все что я перепробовала:

```
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
   _______________________________________

    SetForegroundWindow (hwnd);
   _______________________________________
    var procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Soft");
                foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in procs)
                {
                    ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 1);
                    SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
                }
```

Все это работает, если приложение не перекрыто например браузером, но если перекрыто, то иконка приложения просто мигает в панеле задач и она не сможет принять клики и пр, пока не активируешь её сам мышкой(

Но мне нужна полная автоматизация. Возможно это будет граничить с вирусом, но я делаю это для одного клиента, он не сможет всегда нажимать на программу самостоятельно. 
Я реально перепробовала много вариантов, попробуйте сами, если у вас получится, то надеюсь на помощь

Comment: У меня все работает. Может быть у вас где то ошибки.

Comment: Точно работает? Перед запуском другой программы запусти браузер и выжди паузу, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сделал, 3 браузера открыл и три программы, все работает

Comment: Решила проблему методом SetWindowPos

Answer (score 0):

метод SetWindowPos работает для меня